# Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Tags: node.js, nodemon

when i try to use npm start to just start an empty server
this error appears
idk why it decided that nodemon should be there
shouldn't it be in a node_module folder?

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mongodb-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jss",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": " nodemon index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  
    "module": "commonjs",                                
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                     
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

my index.ts

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome");
});
```

i tried nothing for now but i did other projects and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a `&` in my directory name, removed it. This solved the problem.